# java swing: in paintComponent method how to know what to repaint?

Tags: java, swing

My component is bigger than the screen and parts of it are not shown (I will use scrollbars).
When I receive a call in `paintComponent(g)` how do I know what area should I paint?

Comment: You should listen to scroll events, then update viewport size in you component and make decision based on that.

Comment: The JScrollPane internal mechanics should do all of this for you right out of the box.

Comment: Profile your rendering to see if you even need to optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but the problem is you will have to call `repaint()` on the `JScrollPane` each time you get a call in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` of the `JPanel` or else updates on the `JPanel` will not be visible in the `JScrollPane`.

Also I see you want to use `JScrollBar` (or maybe you confused the terminology)? I'd recommend a `JScrollPane`

I made a small example which is a `JPanel` with a grid that will change its colour every 2 seconds (Red to black and vice versa). The `JPanel`/Grid is larger then the `JScrollPane`; regardless we have to call `repaint()` on the `JScrollPane` instance or else the grid wont change colour:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane();
        jsp.setViewportView(new Panel(800, 800, jsp));
        frame.getContentPane().add(jsp);
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    private int across, down;
    private Panel.Tile[][] tiles;
    private Color color = Color.black;
    private final JScrollPane jScrollPane;

    public Panel(int width, int height, JScrollPane jScrollPane) {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.jScrollPane = jScrollPane;
        createTiles();
        changePanelColorTimer();//just something to do to check if its repaints fine
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < across; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < down; j++) {
                g.setColor(color);
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    g.drawRect(tiles[i][j].x + k, tiles[i][j].y + k, tiles[i][j].side - k * 2, tiles[i][j].side - 2 * k);
                }
            }
        }
        updateScrollPane();//refresh the pane after every paint
    }

    //calls repaint on the scrollPane instance
    private void updateScrollPane() {
        jScrollPane.repaint();
    }

    private void createTiles() {
        across = 13;
        down = 9;
        tiles = new Panel.Tile[across][down];

        for (int i = 0; i < across; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < down; j++) {
                tiles[i][j] = new Panel.Tile((i * 50), (j * 50), 50);
            }
        }
    }

    //change the color of the grid lines from black to red and vice versa every 2s
    private void changePanelColorTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (color == Color.black) {
                    color = Color.red;
                } else {
                    color = Color.black;
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(2000);
        timer.start();
    }

    private class Tile {

        int x, y, side;

        public Tile(int inX, int inY, int inSide) {
            x = inX;
            y = inY;
            side = inSide;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Panel` class if we comment the line `updateScrollPane();` in `paintComponent(Graphics g)` we wont see the grid change colour.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the area that actually has to be painted by querying the clip bounds of the `Graphics` object.

The JavaDoc seems to be a bit out-dated for this method: It says, that it may return a `null` clip. However, this is obviously never the case (and other Swing classes also rely on the clip never being `null`!).

The follwing [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrates the difference between using a the clip or painting the whole component:

[image: ClipDemo]

It contains a `JPanel` with a size of 800x800 in a scroll pane. The panel paints a set of rectangles, and prints how many rectangles have been painted.

One can use the "Use clip bounds" checkbox to enable and disable using the clip. When the clip is used, only the *visible* area of the panel is repainted, and the number of rectangles is much lower. (Note that the test whether a rectangle has to be painted or not is rather simple here: It only performs an intersection test of the rectangle with the visible region. For a real application, one would *directly* use the clip bounds to find out which rectangles have to be painted).

This example also shows some of the tricky internals of scroll panes: When the blinking is switched off, and the scroll bars are moved, one can see that - although the whole visible area changes - only a tiny area actually has to be repainted (namely the area that has become visible due to the scrolling). The other part is simply moved as-it-is, by blitting the previous contents. This behavior can be modified with [JViewport.html#setScrollMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setScrollMode-int-).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class PaintRegionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final PaintRegionPanel paintRegionPanel = new PaintRegionPanel();
        paintRegionPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));

        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                paintRegionPanel.changeColor();
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer.start();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(paintRegionPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        final JCheckBox blinkCheckbox = new JCheckBox("Blink", true);
        blinkCheckbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (blinkCheckbox.isSelected())
                {
                    timer.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(blinkCheckbox);


        final JCheckBox useClipCheckbox = new JCheckBox("Use clip bounds");
        useClipCheckbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                paintRegionPanel.setUseClipBounds(
                    useClipCheckbox.isSelected());
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(useClipCheckbox);

        frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PaintRegionPanel extends JPanel
{
    private Color color = Color.BLACK;
    private boolean useClipBounds = false;

    void setUseClipBounds(boolean useClipBounds)
    {
        this.useClipBounds = useClipBounds; 
    }

    void changeColor()
    {
        if (color == Color.BLACK)
        {
            color = Color.RED;
        }
        else
        {
            color = Color.BLACK;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        g.setColor(color);

        Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
        Rectangle ownBounds = new Rectangle(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        System.out.println("clipBounds: " + clipBounds);
        System.out.println(" ownBounds: " + ownBounds);

        Rectangle paintedRegion = null;
        if (useClipBounds)
        {
            System.out.println("Using clipBounds");
            paintedRegion = clipBounds;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Using ownBounds");
            paintedRegion = ownBounds;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        // This loop performs a a simple test see whether the objects 
        // have to be painted. In a real application, one would 
        // probably use the clip information to ONLY create the
        // rectangles that actually have to be painted:
        for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += 20)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += 20)
            {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x + 5, y + 5, 10, 10);
                if (r.intersects(paintedRegion))
                {
                    g.fill(r);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Painted "+counter+" rectangles ");
    }

}
```

An aside: For many application cases, such an "optimization" should hardly be necessary. The painted elements are intersected against the clip anyhow, so one will probably not gain much performance. When "preparing" the elements to be painted is computationally expensive, one can consider this as one option. (In the example, "preparing" refers to creating the `Rectangle` instance, but there may be more complicated patterns). But in these cases, there may also be more elegant and easier solutions than manually checking the clip bounds.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are wrong. So I decided to answer the question despide the fact that the question is two years old.

I believe that the correct answer is calling `g.getClipBounds()` inside of `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. It will return the rectangle in the control's coordinate system of the area which is invalidated and must be redrawn.

Comment: You're right. Although this question is rather old, I also added another answer. I wonder how the original answer could prevail, because there are some *really* serious oddities in it...